# Trouble with intersection of infinitely many sets

Tags: analysis

So I have a problem that's asking me to compute the intersection of all sets $S(k)$ such that

$$ S(k) = \left(\frac{k-1}{k}, \frac{2k+1}{k}\right], k \ge 1 $$

My answer is $(1,2)$, but the book's answer is $(0,2)$. Maybe I'm just dumb, but I do not understand why the book's answer would be correct.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The set $S(1)$ is not contained in your interval $(1,2)$.

Comment: Your title and body of the Question specify the *intersection* of sets $S(k)$, but the intersection of sets consists of elements belonging to *all* specified sets.  On this basis I ask that you review your Question for consistency.

Comment: Are you sure that the question isn't about the *union* of these sets?

Comment: It's intersection, I did the union part of the question already.

Comment: $S(k) = (1 -1/k, 2 +1/k]$, so the intersection should be the closed interval $[1,2]$.